# Unable to set the right CORS setting for localhost developement

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, next.js

I am trying to make a localhost network call from a Nextjs frontend (localhost:3000) to my Java springboot server(localhost:5555). However, I keep getting this error on my server(Springboot):

```
 [nio-3000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for OPTIONS "/error", parameters={}

[nio-3000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 403
```

Here is my `WebMvcConfigurer` settings:

```
package com.codaholic.shop.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:5555")
                .exposedHeaders("*")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*");
    }
}
```

This is the console.log error from the nextjs frontend:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/article' from origin 'http://localhost:5555' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

The code for the /v1/article endpoint:

```
    @GetMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Article>> getArticleByUser()
            throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        CustomUserDetails userDetails = (CustomUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        UUID userId = userDetails.getUserId();
        List<Article> articles = articleService.getArticlesByUserId(userId);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(articles);
    };
```

However, I am able to make another API call to login without running into the same error.
I am not sure which configuration I am missing or how else I can debug this.

I am using springboot 3.1.3

*** Edit 1 ***
Also just to add on that I actually have a configuration here that disabled `csrf` already:

`SecurityConfiguration.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable()
                )
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize)-> authorize
                    //https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html#match-by-dispatcher-type
                    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/76951737/4973124
                    .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.ERROR).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(
                        "/api/v1/auth/**",
                        "/swagger-ui/**",
                        "/swagger",
                        "/swagger-ui.html"
                    )
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()

            )
            .sessionManagement((session) -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you update `SecurityConfiguration` with `@EnableWebSecurity(debug=true)` and check the error in logs also copy it here, so that we can have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [official spring security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/integrations/cors.html) Try adding or config this bean in your security config for CORS config:

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:5555"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

or just try disabling CORS:

```
@Bean
SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http
        // ...
        .cors(cors -> cors.disable());
    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: Hi Oscar, I tried adding it like this but it didn't work:
`@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/article")
public class ArticleController {`

Comment: Hi @Oscar, thanks for the suggestion - turns out I already have `csrf` disabled - or at least I think it is. You can check out Edit1 above and it still doesnt seem to work.

Comment: I see. Seems it's well disabled. I updated my answer about cors. I think it should solve your issue @jcleow

Comment: Thanks, indeed I should have set the corsConfigurationSource with the SecurityConfiguration class. Seems like I can't mix this with the WebMvcConfigurer. Thanks for your help.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors was also very helpful in helping me achieve the solution